# D3 JS Drawing bar charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I'm trying to draw some bar charts in JS using D3. So what I've done until now is:

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg").attr("width", 500).attr("height", 200);
svg.selectAll("rect").... //drawing the bars
svg.selectAll("text").... //putting labels on top of bars
```

But when I am trying to put the labels, I need them to be in the top-middle of the bars. But to know where to put them I need to somehow reference those d3 objects for the bars... how can I do that?

Comment: are you using scales for the visualization?

Comment: @tomtomtom yes, I am.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using an  `xScale` for the svg, you can use this attribute to place the text:

```
.attr("x", function(d, i) { return xScale(i) + xScale.rangeBand() / 2; })
```

provided the xScale is set like:

```
var xScale = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .domain(d3.range(dataset.length))
    .rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.05);
```

where `w` in the scale is the width of the svg document

Comment: I am only using a y scale, I'm afraid. Isn't it possible to somehow refer to the drawn rectangles?

Comment: P.S. I've tried extracting it like this: var xPos = parseFloat(d3.selectAll("rect").attr("x")); But that just overrides it instead.

Comment: to refer to the middle of each bar you would have to do something like: .attr("x", function (d,i) {((width/dataset.length)/2)*i;})
where (width/dataset.length)/2 should give you the half of each bar, and the *i should put the text on the correct place on the x axis

Comment: Thanks, to what do I play .attr though?

Comment: because I will be doing this in svg.selectAll("text") rather than in svg.selectAll("rect") I can't reference the parent object by doing d3.select(this).

Comment: post all the code you did so far in the main post, I can't help you with what you posted

Comment: I managed to see the pastebin before it got removed, the text now is appearing with this code: svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(whoIs)
  .enter()
 .append("text")
    .text(function(d) { return d; })
 .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    .attr("x", function (d,i){return  + leftMargin + (i* ((svgW/whoIs.length) + leftMargin))/2 ;})
.attr("y", 20);

still needs some tweaking on the positioning. Also note that the last bar is not completely in the frame

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

- [Horizontal Bar Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2141479) example
- [Vertical Bar Charts](http://bl.ocks.org/Guerino1/2164562) example

Each shows how to position labels.

For example, at the end of each horizontal bar...

```
  // Create text values that go at end of each bar...
  canvas.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataSet) // Bind dataSet to text elements
    .enter().append("svg:text") // Append text elements
      .attr("x", x)
      .attr("y", function(d, i) { return y(i); })
      //.attr("y", function(d) { return y(d) + y.rangeBand() / 2; })
      .attr("dx", function(d) { return x(d.magnitude) - 5; })
      .attr("dy", barHeight-5) // vertical-align: middle
      .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
      .text(function(d) { return d.magnitude;})
      .attr("fill", "White");
```

Or text at the top of each vertical bar...

```
  // Create text values that go at top of each bar...
  canvas.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataSet) // Instruct to bind dataSet to text elements
    .enter().append("svg:text") // Append text elements
  // Identify root coordinate (x,y)
      //.attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth; }) // <-- Can't use because of bug in FireFox
      .attr("x", function(d, i) { return x(i) + barWidth / 2; }) // <-- Using because of bug in Firefox
  // Note: the following "+1" offset places value above bar in
  // Space between the top of the bar and the top of the canvas.
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return canvasHeight - y(d.magnitude ); })
      //.attr("dx", -barWidth/2) // <-------------- Can't use because of bug in FireFox
      .attr("dy", "1em") // Controls padding to place text above bars
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text(function(d) { return d.magnitude;})
      .attr("fill", "Black");
```

I hope this helps.